# Unity Texture2D.getPixel different from image pixel value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to load an image and get each pixel color that exist. I made a 100 x 100 image that I load and gets the flatten 2d pixel array.

```
Sprite map = Resources.Load("Sprite/Screen/MapNewNet", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite; 
Color[] colorMap = map.texture.GetPixels();
```

In the image exist only 2 colors. Black(0,0,0) and Green(51,255,51)
I made the image myself and confirmed that the colors of the green image is indeed 51, 255, 51. Through paint & paint.net.
The green color is equal (0.2, 1, 0.2) in normalized values.
Now for some reason when i load the image and write out the color of each pixel i get:
for black ones:

```
RGBA(0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000)
```

and for green ones:

```
RGBA(0.192, 1.000, 0.192, 1.000)
```

The green color 0.192 * 255 equals 48.96 ... and I cannot figure this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the quality of the image compression was to low, In the image Import Settings I changed the Compression to High Quality and that did it.